# Create a BaseClass for ContentPage

Tags: c#, maui

In my `MAUI` project, I have a lot of views as `ContentPage` that share some common functions. So, I want to create a base class with those functions to use across the ContentPages.

Every page has different viewmodels, UI and all the usual components (like `DisplayAlert`). Based on another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69468329/let-maui-page-inherit-form-custom-base-class) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74972784/maui-contentview-cant-inherit-from-custom-base-class), I wrote my base class

```
public abstract class BaseContentPageClass<T> : ContentPage 
                      where T : BaseViewModel
{
    public BaseContentPageClass(T viewModel, string pageTitle)
    {
        BindingContext = ViewModel = viewModel;
        Title = pageTitle;
    }

    protected T ViewModel { get; }
}
```

Then, I like to have a base class for the `ContentView` that has to display advertisements, for example. So, I created another class `BaseAdvClass` based on the base class

```
public partial class BaseAdvClass<T> : 
       BaseContentPageClass<T> where T : BaseViewModel
{
    #region Variables
    public bool ShouldSetEvents { get; set; } = true;
    public long Points { get; set; } = 100;

    private readonly UserSettings settings;
    #endregion

    public BaseAdvClass(T viewModel, string pageTitle, UserSettings settings) 
           : base(viewModel, pageTitle)
    {
        this.settings = settings;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then, I created a new `ContentPage` named *ProfilePage* and this is the XAML and the code behind:

```
<local:BaseAdvClass xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:lang="clr-namespace:MyProject"
         x:Class="MyProject.Views.ProfilePage"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views">

public class ProfilePage : BaseAdvClass<ProfilePageViewModel>
{
    ProfilePageViewModel vm;

    private bool _shouldSetEvents = true;

    public ProfilePage(ProfilePageViewModel model, UserSettings settings) 
           : base(model, "", settings)
    {
    }

    // ...
}
```

At this point the build raises a lot of errors:

- Using the generic type 'BaseAdvClass' requires 1 type arguments (LanguageInUse)
- in the code behind for the base, it requires the class as `partial` but when I add `partial` I get another error

[image: class without partial]

[image: class with partial]

- in this page `DisplayAlert` doesn't exist in the current context
- in the `BaseAdvClass`, InitializeComponent doesn't exist in the current context
- if I add in the constructor of `BaseContentPageClass` the `InitializeComponent` I get the same error (doesn't exist in the current context)

Comment: I don’t think you can do this because XAML doesn’t understand generic type arguments

Comment: Why do you even need to use the ViewModel as a type argument? You already have a BaseViewModel, which all ViewModels can inherit from.

Comment: I saw the code in the other posts like that.